# Fullcalendar v5 Angular CSS Customization not working

Tags: html, css, angular, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-5

I'm using Fullcalendar v5 in our Angular project and want to change, lets say, the Fullcalendar toolbar title color and size.

In my styles.scss I added following CSS code:

```
.fc .fc-toolbar-title {
  font-size: 1.2em;
  color: blue !important;
}
```

To rule out possible implementation errors I also retried this using the [agular example project](https://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar-example-projects/tree/master/angular). The custom CSS changes are not applied here either. I guess it's because the Fullcalendar stylesheet is loaded AFTER my statements.

How can further CSS adjustments be made to the fullcalendar (except for the provided common CSS variables)?

Comment: Okay, I was able to solve it myself. Just add the custom CSS code statements in the globas.scss file, which will be applied after the fullcalendar stylesheet.

Comment: If you found the solution, then post it fully as an Answer below, so that others can benefit from the knowledge (and you can benefit from upvotes!). See also https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer . Comments are not searchable so no-one will find your solution if you just leave it where it is, and also it lacks a proper code example so it's harder for people to use. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I was able to solve it myself. Just add the custom CSS code statements in the globas.scss file, which will be applied after the fullcalendar stylesheet.